# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting ( Data upload to thinkspeak)

Tags: python, python-3.x, upload

I'm really new to python and I'm having trouble with this code

```
import time
import requests

temp = [12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,12,10]
humi = [67,68,69,50,56,57,59,59,45,48]

for x in range(10):
    print ('Uploading sample',x,'...')
    resp=requests.get('https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=WTJJF5W2CL8IGT19&field1=0' %(temp[x],humi[x]))
    time.sleep(20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### String Formatting

```py
>>> "Hi I am %s and I am %d years old"%("PSKP", 22)
Hi I am PSKP and I am 22 years old
```

Like this string formatting is used. means arguments you passed after `%` in brackets must match `%s` `%d` inside that sting.

In your case, sting `https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=WTJJF5W2CL8IGT19&field1=0` don't have any position which can be filled by given values.

If you share API call format with question, we can figure it out how to use it? ;-)

### Edit

```py
import time
import requests

temp = [12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,12,10]
humi = [67,68,69,50,56,57,59,59,45,48]

for x in range(10):
    print ('Uploading sample',x,'...')
    resp=requests.get('https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=WTJJF5W2CL8IGT19&field1=0&temp=%d&humi=%d' %(temp[x],humi[x]))
    time.sleep(20)
```

This is working

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. How do i share the API call format? Im really sorry for asking a stupid question. Im really new to this

Comment: means API accepting which values at server. We need to send these values. For example, you are sending `temp[x]` and `humi[x]` but how server get to know which value is which because server only getting 2 values. Try my code and check you are getting appropriate results. And please what will be output on server when this code execute successfully?

Comment: The code is working now!!! https://thingspeak.com/channels/1065913 Here is the link for the website!!!